# Rails recursive association with migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have a table named Nodes. Each node belongs to one father of the same table, and has one child on the same table too. This is the Node model:

```
class Node < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :parent # I tried using :node instead of :parent
    has_one :children # Same than above
end
```

How can I easily achieve this?

Comment: Why `has_one :children`? It makes no sense to not have `has_many :children, class_name: 'Node'.`

Comment: Yes, you are right in my ER diagram I have one-to-many, I miss that, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I belive what you are looking for is something like this:

```
class CreateNodes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :nodes do |t|
      t.belongs_to :parent, 
        foreign_key: { to_table: :nodes },
        null: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
class Node < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Node', optional: true
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Node', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
end
```

It sets up a self-referential 1-to-many association between a node and its children.

Answer (score 2):

[Self-Referential Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association)

```
class Node < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :parent , :class_name => "Node", :foreign_key => "parent_id", optional: true
    has_one :child, :class_name => "Node", :foreign_key => "parent_id" 
end
```

In that case you should have `parent_id` in `Node` model. Also for `has_one` relationship it should be `child` not `children` by convention.

Query will be like this: -

```
parent = Node.create(parent_id: nil)
child = Node.create(parent_id: parent.id)
```

Get all parent =>

```
Node.where(parent_id: nil)
```

Get child of a parent =>

```
parent.child
```

Comment: Thanks, this also helped me to figure out how this work.